# How to get a JSON data from chrome storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have worked my head off trying different possible solutions for this and nothing works, If I post my different codes that I tried, It causes a lot of confusion, so I kept this question short.

Say I have an object as follows:

```
object1= ["vlah", "", "", "", "", "marc", "aojesl", "", "", ""]
```

Converting it to JSON and setting objectA as key for the object1:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'objectA': JSON.stringify(object1)});
```

How do retrieve or get/parse the JSON object from chrome storage to store its values again in an object?

Comment: Can't you just use `JSON.parse(jsonAsString)`?

Comment: because JSON.parse doesnt work inside the chrome.storage callback function

Comment: There's no need for JSON at all because the storage can store objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `chrome.storage.sync.get` you can get the whole storage. The first argument is an array of the keys you are interested in, in your case only `'objectA'`. Your second argument is the callback function, that will be called once the value(s) has/have been found. The callback will be called with a `result` object, which is your storage with only the keys you have specified. Now you can use `result.objectA` to get your string and `JSON.parse()` to convert it back to an object.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['objectA'], function(result) {
      const objectA = JSON.parse(result.objectA);
});
```

Further reading:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: this will result in null or undefined as the JSON.parse doesnt work inside the chrome.storage callback function

Comment: @brittneymarcotte your information must be wrong, here is a working proof of concept: https://gist.github.com/FoseFx/ded437d4f1e3b64c61867490f001eeb1